# Error : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, runtime-error

I'm trying to create a simple table but it's giving me an error says:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE dj_abonent
(
nr_klienti int NOT NULL,
emer_klienti varchar2(10),
sasia_cel int
CONSTRAINT dj_klientID PRIMARY KEY(nr_klienti)
)
Error at Command Line : 6 Column : 35
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE dj_abonent
(
nr_klienti int NOT NULL,
emer_klienti varchar2(10),
sasia_cel int,
CONSTRAINT dj_klientID PRIMARY KEY(nr_klienti)
)
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 14
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have the second error because you use `dj_klientID` as name for both of the constraints. They have to be unique.

Try renaming one of the two constraints and also your second query will be fixed.

Comment: I try this one but it's giving me the same error:                  Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE dj_abonent
(
dj_klientID int PRIMARY KEY,
emer_klienti varchar2(10),
sasia_cel int
)
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 14
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I guess the message is right and the table you are trying to create already exists. Try to drop it first or alter it.

Comment: I drop it and than I created it again. it works. thank you for your time

Comment: No problem. If all your problems are resolved. Don't forget to mark your question as answered. See the [FAQ#why-vote] why.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a comma:

```
CREATE TABLE dj_abonent
(
nr_klienti int NOT NULL,
emer_klienti varchar2(10),
sasia_cel int, -- this one right here
CONSTRAINT dj_klientID PRIMARY KEY(nr_klienti)
)
```

Comment: I fix it but its the same problem..                                     Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE dj_abonent
(
nr_klienti int NOT NULL,
emer_klienti varchar2(10),
sasia_cel int,
CONSTRAINT dj_klientID PRIMARY KEY(nr_klienti)
)
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 14
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action: