# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when creating tables

Tags: oracle11g, runtime-error

I am trying to create 3 tables but I am getting this error:

```
CREATE TABLE dj_abonent 
( 
dj_klientID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
emer_klienti varchar2(10), 
mbiemer_klienti VARCHAR2(10),
sasia_cel INT
);

CREATE TABLE dj_phones
(
 phone_number varchar2(12),
 activated number(1) default 0,
 activation_date date default null,
 CONSTRAINT dj_phone_number_check
CHECK (substr(phone_number,1,5) in( '35566','35567','35568','35569') ),
 CONSTRAINT dj_activated_check
  CHECK (activated in(1,0) ) 
dj_KlientID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dj_Abonenti(dj_KlientID)
);

CREATE TABLE dj_telef
(
start_time date,
end_time date,
abonent_1 varchar2(10),
abonent_2 varchar2(10)
);

Error at Command Line : 26 Column : 17
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: You seem to be learning some basics and asking questions about every error you encounter; it isn't clear if you're really doing much investigation or experimentation yourself, or really taking on board the answers you're getting. We're generally happy to help, but only if you show effort too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line number is from your SQL Developer script window, which isn't entirely helpful as it doesn't seem to align with the issue. There may be other things too but you're missing a comma after your check constraint (just like [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22467194/266304)). But you should put the constraints at the end of the command:

```
CREATE TABLE dj_phones
(
 phone_number varchar2(12),
 activated number(1) default 0,
 activation_date date default null,
 dj_KlientID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dj_Abonenti(dj_KlientID)
 CONSTRAINT dj_phone_number_check
  CHECK (substr(phone_number,1,5) in( '35566','35567','35568','35569') ),
 CONSTRAINT dj_activated_check
  CHECK (activated in(1,0) ) 
);
```

You might find it easier to debug these issues if you ran one statement at a time, either with the run statement command (control-enter), or by highlighting the text one one command and using run script (F5).